# Problem when serializing and de-serializing RichTextBox in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, serialization

I have an experimental WPF probject like Microsoft Word. The main component is `RichTextBox`. Users can edit the content and save it to somewhere. The below methods are used in serializing and deserializing the content to/from a remote database.

```
public static byte[] FlowDocumentSerializingV2WithXamlWriter(FlowDocument flowDocument) {
    using(MemoryStream buffer = new MemoryStream()) {
        XamlWriter.Save(flowDocument, buffer);
        return buffer.ToArray();
    }
}
```

I serialize `RichTextBox.Document` using the above method. This method returns a `byte[]`. I save the `byte[]` result to a remote database. Later, we can read this `byte[]` data from the remote database and then load it into the `RichTextBox` using below method.

```
public FlowDocument FlowDocumentDeserializingV2WithXamlLoader(byte[] data) {
    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(data);          
    return (FlowDocument)XamlReader.Load(ms);
}
```

If there is no image in the `FlowDocument`, the above methods work very well. The problem is that when any picture is pasted in the `FlowDocument`, `FlowDocumentDeserializingV2WithXamlLoader(byte[] data)` will throw an exception on the line `return (FlowDocument)XamlReader.Load(ms)`. The exception is:

> System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException
>
> HResult=0x80131501
> Message='Initialization of 'System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage' threw an exception.' Line number '1' and line position '123355'.
> Source=PresentationFramework
> StackTrace: at System.Windows.Markup.XamlReader.RewrapException(Exception e, IXamlLineInfo lineInfo, Uri baseUri)
>
> This exception was originally thrown at this call stack:
>
> ```
> System.Net.WebRequest.Create(System.Uri, bool)  
> MS.Internal.WpfWebRequestHelper.CreateRequest(System.Uri)  
> System.IO.Packaging.PackWebRequest.GetRequest(bool)  
> System.IO.Packaging.PackWebRequest.GetResponse()  
> MS.Internal.WpfWebRequestHelper.GetResponse(System.Net.WebRequest)
> System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapDecoder.SetupDecoderFromUriOrStream(System.Uri, System.IO.Stream, System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapCacheOption, out System.Guid, out bool, out System.IO.Stream, out System.IO.UnmanagedMemoryStream, out Microsoft.Win32.SafeHandles.SafeFileHandle)
> System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapDecoder.CreateFromUriOrStream(System.Uri, System.Uri, System.IO.Stream, System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapCreateOptions, System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapCacheOption, System.Net.Cache.RequestCachePolicy, bool)
> System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage.FinalizeCreation()
> System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage.EndInit()
> MS.Internal.Xaml.Runtime.ClrObjectRuntime.InitializationGuard(System.Xaml.XamlType, object, bool)
> ```
>
> Inner Exception 1:
> NotSupportedException: The URI prefix is not recognized.

I don't know how to fix this problem. Can anybody help me? Any help is appreciating.

Comment: This same problem doesn't happen for me. I made a test project with your code. I copied a random doodle from MS Paint into the RichTextBox and then ran your code. It didn't throw an exception. Maybe it depends on where you copy the image from?

Comment: Thanks, Keith. Seems I missed something in the post. In my case, I saved the byte[] data into DB(Sqlite 3). Then close the program and re-open again. Please note that the program must be closed and then re-open again. then loading the byte[] data to RichTextBox. The exception will appear.

Answer (score 0):

I have created a project to demonstrate this issue in Github: https://github.com/apchee/richtextbox

The images in `readme.md` is not showing, but it should be shown in local computer.